# Interview Advice

Tags: angular, reactjs

Yesterday I had an Interview for a React Developer position... but I got a little confused about which kind of answer the guy who talked to me was looking for:

He asked: Let suppose that the back-end is fine, and your app is slowing down, like freezing, through some function. What do you do to discover what's happening?

So, I answered: I would check compile output, all the TDD outputs and their execution time. If I don't find any problem or a problem indicator, I would check the code looking for recursive functions, pieces of code where a refactoring should be done and also how the data were handled.

However the interviewer  looks kind of disappointed! And also said that one of the answer should be like "I check if all the files was bundled" !

So, as I'm a beginner I would like know how would be the best answer and/or what I should study to figure out...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible answers, what I think he expected was that you need to make sure that a component is not re-rendered X times more than it should be.

For instance, if you `setState` without checking for redundancy, your component/App will render a lot more than it should if you did the necessary checks. 
For more info, check out an existing tool that does it for you (there are plenty): https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update

Hope that helped!